# Display WP posts in 3 responsive columns

Tags: php, columns, responsive, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display 6 random WordPress posts in 3 responsive columns, 2 rows, by using:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query("showposts=6&cat=1&orderby=rand");?>
```

For example,

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        Random Post 1
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        Random Post 2
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        Random Post 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        Random Post 4
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        Random Post 5
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        Random Post 6
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm using WP Bootstrap. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query("showposts=6&cat=1&orderby=rand");
    while ( $the_query ->have_posts() ) {$the_query ->the_post(); $i++;
        if ($i == 1){echo "<div class=row-fluid>";}
        ?>
            <div class="span4">
                Random Post <?php echo $i ; ?>
            </div>
        <?php
        if ($i == 3){echo "</div><div class=row-fluid>";}
        if ($i == 6){echo "</div>";$i=0;}
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: You should declare `$i` somewhere. And you might care to check out [PHP's modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).